# Blocking Ctrl-C / Ctrl-Z in an input command

Tags: matlab, octave, ctrl

In Matlab or GNU Octave, this command `input("")` allows to break the input process by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Is there a way to block this, so that only a valid input is accepted?

Note: Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on an input command even exits the Octave shell in a Linux terminal, so I understand that the control must be established at a different layer.

Comment: Don't have the answer, but are you looking for a solution that works when you run the code inside matlab, or when you have already deployed it and run it separately?- And perhaps it can be interesting to know why you want this.

Comment: I meant from the command prompt. In general it won't be a feature that you might want to include, but I'm programming for an inexperienced user, who is not intended to know about Octave or Linux.

Comment: CTRL+Z doesn't "exit" Octave, see "bash job control"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want `input` to **ignore** when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is pushed?  I don't think that's possible simply because this could potentially be dangerous.  Ignoring listening to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> could open the possibility of your code running endlessly and you not being able to break out of the code unless you manually kill MATLAB. I'm not saying that what you desire with `input` will be dangerous, but if MATLAB allowed you to ignore this keystroke in any capacity, then you'd have that dangerous situation that I talked about if used improperly.

FWIW, check out this link on MATLAB Central:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25213-disabling-ctrl-c-in-a-gui .  Here, someone is trying to ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> so that their GUI doesn't needlessly crash, but MathWorks confirms that it is not possible to do so.

Comment: Yes, I know it's tricky, but in some situations, like customizing a program for inexperienced users, an eventual crash is the end of the story. Thx!

Comment: @nightcod3r - My pleasure.  I'm sorry if this isn't what you wanted to hear, but at least it's a definitive answer.  Good luck!